# Unmanaged library function fails when called from C# but not C++

Tags: c#, c++, mono, pinvoke, dllimport

I am trying to create a Mono/.Net wrapper class around an existing C++ shared library, but I am running into issues while the unmanaged code is executing.  Although I am successfully calling into the library, the unmanaged code is throwing a segmentation fault.  This does not happen when I call the library function from an unmanaged application written in C++.

C++ Header code:

```
extern "C" void some_function();
```

C++ Source code:

```
void some_function()
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> v = std::vector<uint8_t> { 0x00 };
}
```

C# P/Invoke code:

```
[DllImport("somelib.so", EntryPoint = "some_function")]
public static extern void some_function();
```

As you can see, there are no parameters that need marshaling, so the problem isn't with data that is being passed in.  I am having this problem with several functions in this library, but I am also able to call several without any issues.  Usually the segfault occurs when attempting to allocate memory (in at least one case it's for an std::vector), but not always.  I have attempted to debug in gdb, and have noticed that there are 5 threads when called from C#, but only 1 when called from C++.  I am also doing this with Mono on Ubuntu, if that makes a significant difference.

Is there anything I may have missed while implementing my P/Invoke calls, or is there something else going on here?

UPDATE:  I have added a second, simpler example function that is having the same issue as the first.

UPDATE:  I have removed the first example, and provided a simple yet full implementation of the problem.  My earlier tests did not have me initializing the vector with values.  I've tried several methods of initializing the vector, but none work.  It seems the segfault occurs whenever memory is allocated for a new item in the vector, including during initialization.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, the default calling convention for Mono on Unix platforms is `cdecl`. Which presumably matches your C++ code. So I guess that's not the problem. Worth double-checking though. Perhaps specify the calling convention explicitly in your pinvoke.

I don't understand why you are using `UnmanagedType.Struct` for the return value. So far as I can tell that is not correct. On .net that would result in the struct being marshalled as a `VARIANT` which is absolutely not what you want. I'm not sure whether `UnmanagedType.Struct` has any meaning for Mono pinvoke on Linux, but in any case it should not be present so you should remove it.

Nor is there any need to name the entry point. So I'd simplify the p/invoke.

```
[DllImport("somelib.so")]
public static extern some_struct some_function();
```

The other obvious potential mismatch would be between your native and managed struct definitions. You said:

> As you can see, there are no parameters that need marshaling, so the problem isn't with data that is being passed in.

That's true, but what about the return value being passed out. That needs marshalling too, and you've got to get it right. Without being able to see definitions of your struct types (both native and managed), we're in no position to judge. If you cannot show them here, then you'll have to check that they match.

Finally, it is conceivable the your compiler and the pinvoke marshaller assume a different ABI for struct return values. That is always a grey area. I would always recommend simple types as return values and return your struct as an out parameter.

If I had to bet, I'd say that the problem lies in the struct definitions, which sadly you have not shown.

---

**Update**

Your question edit indicates that you have problems with a function that has `void` return type. In which case the only sane conclusion is that the problem is in your native code and not in the p/invoke. To track this down further, you'll need to look at the native code.

Comment: I should have added that I have tried modifying the function to return void, both in C# and C++, but still get the same segfault.  The function always fails long before any return value is created, so I have been ruling out any problems marshaling the return value.  I plan on figuring out the return value problems once I can get the code to execute that far.

Comment: You should have added? If you believe that the return value doesn't matter, why is it even in the question? Is it possible that the problem is with the native code? How about you post an SSCCE? Otherwise you are unlikely to get any response different from mine.

Comment: I fully expect the problem to be with the native code, however I don't understand what to look for when it fails only when called from managed code.  As far as I can tell, the native code looks fine.  Once I know what's wrong, I may be able to modify the native code to fix the issue.  I have tried reproducing the problem with an SSCCE (like initializing a std::vector on the unmanaged side), but have not been able to do so.  Simple cases all work, many of the actual functions I'm calling do not.  Thanks for the insights.

Comment: Sounds to me like you've already proved that the issue is not in the pinvoke. In which case I'm not sure what the question is driving at. If you could not make a simple SSCCE, then the problem isn't to do with your pinvoke. I think I've listed all the possible problem areas with your pinvoke. I'm sorry that this has not been helpful to you. By the way, what made you use `UnmanagedType.Struct`?

Comment: The UnmanagedType.Struct came from some example code I found on how to marshal nested structs.  Since I haven't gotten the application to run far enough to hit the return value, I haven't found out if this is correct or not.  I also agree that the problem isn't with pinvoke.  My best guess is that the native code is somehow allocating memory that should be managed by Mono.  However, if that were the case, I would expect the failure to occur once I stepped back into managed code.  I'm hoping someone in the community recognizes what is going on here, and can help point me to the fix.

Comment: Nobody can do any more with what you have given us. All we have got is `some_other_function`. The C# and C++ versions. Since they have no parameters, and no return value, and are both `cdecl`, they work. Your test program that has do nothing implementation of `some_other_function` will work fine. So the problem is clearly in the code that only you can see. Do you really expect the community to help diagnose a fault in something that it cannot see? Produce an SSCCE and you will get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact issue recently. I was unable to allocate `std::vector` or `std::map` without crashing to access violation when calling a function in an unmanaged DLL from a managed executable. Similarly, everything worked when calling directly from unmanaged executable.

In our case, the problem turned out to be that a wrong (and possibly broken) std DLL was being loaded at runtime when invoked from managed context, and simply removing the location of this DLL from PATH fixed the issue.

This was difficult to identify as the error message initially gave no hints what could be the cause, but after linking the standard libraries dynamically (instead of the default static linking), the access violation identified the std DLL in question, leading into the discovery of the wrong binaries in PATH.